# Deploying MariaDB Columnstore Docker image in Azure

Tags: mysql, mariadb, azure, docker

I deployed the [MariaDB Columnstore Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/mariadb/columnstore) in Windows with the following command:

```
docker container run  --name cont_mariadb  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=xxxxxxx 
       -p 3306:3306  -v vol_mariadb:/var/lib/mysql -d mariadb/columnstore
```

This worked fine, including the external storage with the volume.

Next, I tried to do the same in Azure. I created a container instance with a volume in the file storage account. The creation had no issues, but when I start the container I see the following errors in the log:

> 201226 23:39:27 mysqld_safe Starting mariadbd daemon with databases
> from /var/lib/mysql /usr/share/mysql/mysql.server: line 264: kill:
> (411) - No such process . ERROR!
>
> ....
> 'mysqld_safe' failed to start (exit status 0) -- '/usr/bin/columnstore-restart':
> /usr/share/mysql/mysql.server: line 264: kill: (665) - No such process

Following some research, I granted to the mysql user permission to the volume data directory and restarted the container:

```
sudo chown -R mysql:root /var/lib/mysql
```

Now I only have an error similar to the second error I had previously (mysqld_safe):

> 201226 23:49:18 mysqld_safe Starting mariadbd daemon with databases
> from /var/lib/mysql . ERROR!  /usr/share/mysql/mysql.server: line 264:
> kill: (402) - No such process

If I try to start an SQL command line in the container with `mysql -u root` I get the following error, indicating that mysql is not active:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

There's information about deploying MariaDB in Docker (not exactly the same as it's not the Columnstore version, but I thought it may help).

It talks about [disabling AppArmor](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-and-using-mariadb-via-docker/#troubleshooting-a-container). But AppArmor is not in the columnstore image (it may be in the regular MariaDB image):

```
# yum list app*

Available Packages
appliance-tools.noarch                 011.1-1.el8                             epel
apprise.noarch                         0.8.9-1.el8                             epel
appstream-data.noarch                  8-20200724.el8                          AppStream
```

Any ideas on how to make this work will be greatly appreciated.